# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate not working for merge

Tags: spring, db2, jdbctemplate

I am running the below merge query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate.

The batchUpdate(String sql, SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs) works for batchArgs with 1 item and does not work for multiple items. Below is the query and I renamed table column names.

The NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate works if run for each array item seperately or if run as NamedParameterJdbcTemplate .update()

Sql Query:

```
MERGE INTO tableName C1 USING (VALUES (:f1)) AS C2(Field1)    
ON (C1.CMP = C2.CO_C)     
WHEN MATCHED THEN      
   UPDATE SET Field2 = :date1, Field3 = :time1, Field4 =:userId                    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN     
    INSERT (Field5, Field1, Field4, Field2, Field3) VALUES (:offCC, :f1,:userId, :date1, :time1)
```

> [err] SQL exception:
>   [err]  Message: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.22.29] Batch failure. The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch. Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
>   [err]  SQLSTATE: null
>   [err]  Error code: -4229
>   [err] SQL exception:
>   [err]  Message: VARIABLE  IS NOT DEFINED OR NOT USABLE.
>   SQLCODE=-312,   SQLSTATE=42618, DRIVER=4.22.29
>   [err]  SQLSTATE: 42618
>   [err]  Error code: -312
>   [err] SQL exception:
>   [err]  Message: Error for batch element #1: VARIABLE  IS NOT DEFINED OR  NOT USABLE
>   [err]  SQLSTATE: 42618
>   [err]  Error code: -312

Comment: are all those records you are inserting follow database data type  , such as a var is declared 50 chars and you are passing 100 chars value in one of the record in batch update.Try your code with 2-3 records and see if you still see this error.

Comment: The values are fine with the db data types, I tried with 1 and 2 records and had this error. I ran the sql seperately in sql client, and sql ran fine. So still seeing the issue.  Some how the parameters in prepared statement are not being mapped.

Comment: Can you show your code to populate these parameters. Also the sql query u run in dB .Clearly it says , there is a type mismatch .